# Reader and Writer for dynamic json in scala play-json

Tags: scala, play-json

Is it possible write Reader and Writer for dymanic json. For example we have json:

```
{
   "type": "LOGIN",
    "source": {}
 }
```

So source could be different objects, depends of type. For type LOGIN it could be:

```
"source": {"username": "name", "password": "password"}
```

For recieving some message, type=MESSAGE:

```
"source": {"message": "hello"}
```

in official website there are examples like this:

```
   implicit val memberReads: Reads[Event] = (
      (JsPath \ "type").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "source").read[Login]
   ) (Event.apply _)
```

But nothing about dynamic json. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Dynamic JSON has no specific meaning, be more specific

Comment: He probably wants monadic parsing. Never used play-json but doing something like `(..).read[String].flatMap { case s @ "LOGIN" => (..).read[Login].map(Event(s, _)) }` might just work there.

Comment: One of fields could have different types depends on another field. Depends on type Source field could be case class Login or case class Message...

Comment: That's a discriminator field, and play-json supports that to map with sealed trait/family